# Xcode swiftで、配置した[戻る]ボタンから[Exit]にドラッグして戻り口を作りたい

Tags: swift

Xcode swiftで、配置した[戻る]ボタンから[Exit]にドラッグして戻り口を作りたいのですが、接続されません。

親画面のviewcontrollerには

@IBAction func returnTop(segue: UIStoryboadSegue) {}

と記述したのですが、警告でuse of undeclared type 'UIStoryboadSegue'と表示されてしまいます。

ググったのですが初心者すぎてイマイチ理解できません…(･･;)
恐縮ですがよろしくお願いします

Comment: [戻る]はボタンだとして、[Exit]は一体何を表すのでしょうか?「親画面」が
あるということは子画面もあるのでしょうか?[戻る]ボタンはどちらにあるのでしょう?「ドラッグして」と言う具体的な実現方法ではなく、[戻る]ボタンを押したときに一体何が起こるようにしたいのかをきちんと記述し直された方が、より適切な回答を得やすくなるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: See.Ku さんの回答を見てようやく理解できました。わかってから改めて見ると、「それくらいは最初からわかってて良いはずでしょ」ってレベルまでは記述していただいていますね。失礼しました。

Comment: 本件解決いたしました！
質問がわかりづらくなってしまい申し訳ございません(;_;)
回答していただきありがとうございました！

Comment: user14762 さん、Xcode上での操作であることは明記してあったのに、うまく読み取ることができず失礼しました。See.Ku さんの回答が直接解決に結びついたのであれば、「解決」のマーキングをすることができます。よろしければチェックしてみてください。

Answer (score 1):

自分で設置したボタンを押して前の画面に戻る処理を、Storyboardで設定したいと言う事ですよね？

単純な綴りミスのように思われます。正しくは、UIStoryboardSegueでは無いでしょうか？

・修正前

```
@IBAction func returnTop(segue: UIStoryboadSegue) {}
```

・修正後

```
@IBAction func returnTop(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

Comment: 本件解決いたしました！
超初歩的なミスにも優しく回答していただき感謝申し上げます！
ありがとうございました！